# Android variable at "onActivityResult" sometime null value on KITKAT

Tags: android

```
private void openCamera(int imageArray){
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/SurveyDA/assets/images","absen_" +
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"));
    Log.d("ddddd : ", String.valueOf(fileUri));
    cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, imageArray);
}
```

when I want open camera, I set the fileuri, and Log success return uri

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            //getting bitmap object from uri
            Log.d("ddddd : ", String.valueOf(fileUri));
            bitmapImage[requestCode] = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), fileUri);
            // Initialize a new ByteArrayStream
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            // Compress the bitmap with JPEG format and quality 50%
            bitmapImage[requestCode].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,60,stream);

            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
            bitmapImage[requestCode] = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), false);

            //displaying selected image to imageview
            imageViews[requestCode].setImageBitmap(bitmapImage[requestCode]);
            //calling the method uploadBitmap to upload image
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // User Cancelled the actiongetUriForFile
    }
}
```

but in `onActivityResult` variable fileuri sometimes get null, and sometimes success return uri. And when I try in other phone Android 8.0.0, there no error.
how to fix that?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.surveyonlineda/com.example.surveyonlineda.Activity.AbsenActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.surveyonlineda/com.example.surveyonlineda.Activity.AbsenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this Document](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#java) for your issue you will get best solution

Answer (score 0):

as I see, the `fileUri` is not returned by `onActivityResult`. You create it before start your `cameraIntent`. So in case your activity has been destroyed, the `fileUri` will null. To prevent it, I think you should use `onSaveInstanceState` to save the `fileUri`.

Here is an example to save the string fileUri

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of fileUri from saved state
        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getString(FILE_URI);
    } else {
        // Probably initialize values for a new instance
    } 
}

@Override protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putString(FILE_URI, fileUri);
    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState); 
}
```

Comment: how to use `savedInstanceState.getString(FILE_URI)` at `onActivityResult`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it. it worked for me

Step 1. Create class GetPathFromUri.class

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.io.*;

public class GetPathFromUri {
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
    @SuppressLint("ObsoleteSdkInt") final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }
            if ("raw".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }
            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            if ("5D68-9217".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

            if (id != null && id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                return id.substring(4);
            }

            String[] contentUriPrefixesToTry = new String[]{
                    "content://downloads/public_downloads",
                    "content://downloads/my_downloads"
            };

            for (String contentUriPrefix : contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
                Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(contentUriPrefix), Long.valueOf(id));
                try {
                    String path = getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                    if (path != null) {
                        return path;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }

            // path could not be retrieved using ContentResolver, therefore copy file to accessible cache using streams
            String fileName = getFileName(context, uri);
            File cacheDir = getDocumentCacheDir(context);
            File file = generateFileName(fileName, cacheDir);
            String destinationPath = null;
            if (file != null) {
                destinationPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                saveFileFromUri(context, uri, destinationPath);
            }

            return destinationPath;
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};
            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context       The context.
 * @param uri           The Uri to query.
 * @param selection     (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                    String[] selectionArgs) {
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {column};
    try (Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
            null)) {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static String getFileName(@NonNull Context context, Uri uri) {
    String mimeType = context.getContentResolver().getType(uri);
    String filename = null;

    if (mimeType == null && context != null) {
        String path = getPath(context, uri);
        if (path == null) {
            filename = getName(uri.toString());
        } else {
            File file = new File(path);
            filename = file.getName();
        }
    } else {
        Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (returnCursor != null) {
            int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
            returnCursor.moveToFirst();
            filename = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);
            returnCursor.close();
        }
    }

    return filename;
}


public static String getName(String filename) {
    if (filename == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int index = filename.lastIndexOf('/');
    return filename.substring(index + 1);
}

public static File getDocumentCacheDir(@NonNull Context context) {
    File dir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), DOCUMENTS_DIR);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    logDir(context.getCacheDir());
    logDir(dir);

    return dir;
}

public static final String DOCUMENTS_DIR = "documents";
static final String TAG = "FileUtils";
private static final boolean DEBUG = false; // Set to true to enable logging

private static void logDir(File dir) {
    if (!DEBUG) return;
    Log.d(TAG, "Dir=" + dir);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File=" + file.getPath());
    }
}

@Nullable
public static File generateFileName(@Nullable String name, File directory) {
    if (name == null) {
        return null;
    }

    File file = new File(directory, name);

    if (file.exists()) {
        String fileName = name;
        String extension = "";
        int dotIndex = name.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (dotIndex > 0) {
            fileName = name.substring(0, dotIndex);
            extension = name.substring(dotIndex);
        }

        int index = 0;

        while (file.exists()) {
            index++;
            name = fileName + '(' + index + ')' + extension;
            file = new File(directory, name);
        }
    }

    try {
        if (!file.createNewFile()) {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, e);
        return null;
    }

    logDir(directory);

    return file;
}

private static void saveFileFromUri(Context context, Uri uri, String destinationPath) {
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    try {
        is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destinationPath, false));
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        is.read(buf);
        do {
            bos.write(buf);
        } while (is.read(buf) != -1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (is != null) is.close();
            if (bos != null) bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Step 2:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    try {
    String path =  GetPathFromUri.getPath(this, data.getData())
    Glide.with(this).load(path).into(imageView); 
 // Glide is library https://github.com/bumptech/glide
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
    // User Cancelled the actiongetUriForFile
}
}
```

Comment: how to implement to my case?